# Keyboard-Shortcut to open new Browser tab (XFCE Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I'd like to have a global keyboard shortcut that focuses my browser (or starts it if there isn't a running instance), opens a new tab and focuses the URL bar. I'm using Chrome and XFCE.

XFCE seems to have only a few predefined Actions for shortcuts, so I probably need some additional tool and some insight in how to open a new, blank chrome tab from a script or the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Any command can be bound to an available keyboard shortcut with XFCE. In Xubuntu 11.10 I opening the XFCE *Settings Manager*, then click *Keyboard* and then the *Application Shortcuts* tab. I use Chromium, and I can open a new tab/window from a terminal with the `chromium-browser` command, but I'm not sure how to make that new tab open in an existing Chromium window (if there is one).